# Не работает npm run dev laravel

Tags: laravel, npm, vite

Делаю тестовый проект на ларавел, подключил бутстрап, сделал npm i, далее пишу npm run dev, чтобы собрать проект и скомпилировать scss в сss, а он мне пишет [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Пробую npm vite, vite, dev, не хочет и все

Comment: Содержимое vite.config.js ?

Comment: Решил установкой ноды в проект -D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Возможно, у вас устаревшая версия node, проверьте версию с помощью `node --version`

Установить последнюю или любую другую версию можно с помощью NVM (https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm)